# Как выбрать либо то слово либо другое

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь написать такое регулярное выражение, чтобы совпадала только строка, содержащая "qwe" либо "rty".

Вот пример. Сейчас я делаю так:

```
result1 = re.finditer(r"matching plugin (.+)", line, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
for match in result1:
    qwe(1)
result2 = re.finditer(r"error: (.+)", line, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
for match in result2:
    qwe(1)
```

Comment: Примеры приведите, несколько. Где true, где false.

Comment: Есть много движков регулярок. Какой у вас?

Comment: `/qwe|rty/` сработает на строке если она содержит `qwe` или `rty`, только в данном случае надо учесть, что она также сработает и на строке `asdqwedsa`, т.к. в ней встречается `qwe`

Comment: Спасибо ворон, сработало)

Comment: Оно сработает и на строке "qwerty", хотя в ней обе подстроки встречаются ;)

Comment: @Visman, ну так `qwerty` удовлетворяет исходному условию, а вообще уже куча таких вопросов было, надо позакрывать их как дубликаты

Comment: @BOPOH, меня просто смущает заголовок вопроса: Либо ..., либо ...

Comment: Скажу Вам по секрету, что решайте эту задачу не регулярными выражениями, ведь не прочитав абсолютно ничего про них Вы можете получить целую кучу проблем.

Comment: @BOPOH оформите, пожалуйста, Ваш комментарий как ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Ответ перенесен из комментария:

`/qwe|rty/` сработает на строке если она содержит `qwe` или `rty`, только в данном случае надо учесть, что она также сработает и на строке `asdqwedsa`, т.к. в ней встречается `qwe`

Comment: границу слов можно с помощью `\b` обозначить: `r'\b(?:qwe|rty)\b'`